# Processing files off a queue, archiving and storing in a DB

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, ibm-mq

We will be implementing a solution to pull files off of a queue (IBM - MQ).  The messages will be 10-20 different xml messages that will need to be dequeued, processed, and archived (store). However, when we store the data contained in the messages in a DB we want to retain the source file so the FileId that gets generated from the archive process will have to be retained and stored with the meta data.

I am trying to figure out what will provide me with the most throughput?

Requirements:

1. Keep an archive of the file.
2. Store the parsed data (not the xml blob) from the messages.
3. Retain the Source File ID from the Archive.
4. Implement a solution that will scale could grow significantly....currently probably 40-50,000 messages an hour.

So basically my currently bottleneck is that it seems that my archive process and data processing / db load are serial (archive has to process and be successful before I can start on xml parsing / loading).....didn't know if there is a better way to accomplish this.

I would assume we could add other app servers that would be listening on the same queue and could process the messages in parallel if need be.  Try to eliminate the DB as the bottleneck by having it perform as little processing as possible (Could send xml blob to DB, but it would have to perform the xml shredding).

Comment: To answer this question we have to know how large the XML files are that need to be "processed".

Answer (score 0):

1. Work with DBAs to tune writes to the database.
2. Test multiple reads and see if you get better throughput.

My experience is that you'll want to have multiple readers, but the number will depend on lots of factors.  Test it and see what is bets.